# Trimming a data frame value with dot in header

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading an input file with headers having ' . ' dot as DataFrame. I am facing problems trying to trim the values in that file.

Sample testCode:

```
val sqc = new SQLContext(getLocalSparkContext())
import sqc.implicits.localSeqToDataFrameHolder
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val testDataFrame = Seq((" test data ", " dummy data ", " a multi word string  ")).toDF("col1", "col. 2", "col3")
testDataFrame.withColumn("col. 2", trim(testDataFrame("`col. 2`"))).show()
testDataFrame.withColumn("col1", trim(testDataFrame("col1"))).show()
```

If I try to execute the above code, I am getting

> cannot resolve 'col. 2' given input columns col1, col. 2, col3;
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'col. 2' given
>   input columns col1, col. 2, col3;

on this line: `testDataFrame.withColumn("col1", trim(testDataFrame("col1"))).show()`

Surprisingly,

```
testDataFrame.withColumn("col. 2", trim(testDataFrame("`col. 2`"))).show()
```

passes.
I even tried to replace the column like:

```
testDataFrame.withColumnRenamed("col. 2", "`col. 2`").show()
```

Still getting the same exception. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

val t1 = testDataFrame.withColumn("tmp", trim(col("`col. 2`"))).drop(testDataFrame("`col. 2`"))

val t2 = t1.withColumn("col .2", t1("tmp")).drop(t1("tmp"))

Comment: Thanks Udi for your comments. Based on what you provided, I used 
    val testDataFrame = Seq((" test data ", " dummy data ", " a multi word string  ")).toDF("col1", "col. 2", "col3")
    val transformedDF = testDataFrame.withColumn("tmp", trim(testDataFrame("`col. 2`"))).drop("col. 2").withColumnRenamed("tmp", "col. 2")
    transformedDF.show()
    transformedDF.withColumn("col1", trim(testDataFrame("col1"))).show()

The order of the columns have changed, and also the trim on "col1" fails

Comment: The withColumn function on any other column fails when any one of the headers is having ' . '. Hence had to do the same "tmp" column thing for any other columns as well. Hope this gets fixed.